# error in adding play stop music button in existing flash xml as3.0 template

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, addeventlistener

I am trying to edit an existing flash template. Using Flash CS6 and ActionScript 3.0 --- kind of new to this...

I had a footer clip present in the source file. I edited and added two buttons there. The main .fla is by the name of template which has a single layer and actions layer defined and controlled using main.as

I was able to play music successfully by writing in the actions layer here, using these script:

```
var music:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("music.mp3"));
var sc:SoundChannel = music.play();
```

The sound plays well. What the problem I face is in adding play and stop button now. I used the following script to achieve that:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var music:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("music.mp3"));
var sc:SoundChannel = music.play();

btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMusic);

function stopMusic(Event:MouseEvent):void{
    sc.stop;
}

btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMusic);
function playMusic(Event:MouseEvent):void{
    sc = music.play();
}
```

Here i get the error:

> Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 10    1061: Call to a possibly
>   undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type
>   Class.

Kindly guide me how to correct it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill try and guide you kindly.

Your error is telling you that there is no static method called addEventListener in your btnStop class.  when you give a mc a name it creates a new class.  what you are doing is like doing....

```
Sound.play();
```

when you want music.play();

to fix this click on your button in the design part, go to the right, in the properties panel and you need to give your button an instance name of 'btnStop'.  You will have to do the same with your btnPlay button as well. now when you call btnStop in your code youll be calling the instance of the button and not the class itself.

in addition in your stopMusic function you should have:

```
sc.stop();
```

instead of:

```
sc.stop;
```

Also, your parameter names in your two functions cannot be 'Event' Event is the name of a class in the AS3 API. try using the parameter name 'e' or 'event' (case matters).